# react router showing different views within routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React router and trying to set two different views:

The first one `Home` has a user avatar on the left and then depending on the different url a different view is shown next to the image.

This works fine and looks like the below:

```
 ------------------
|       ||         |
| IMAGE || CONTENT |      
|       ||         |
 ------------------
```

However the issue I am having is when I try to navigate to the `pullrequests` route. See in the `App` component below.

In this case I just want to display the `PullRequests` component like so

```
 --------------
|              |
| PULLREQUESTS |       
|              |
 --------------
```

See code below:

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
   <ProfileContainer>

    <div className='left-side'>
     <img src={ avatarUrl }/>
    </div>

    <div className='right-side'>
      <InformationContainer>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Repositories}/>
        <Route path="/followers" component={Followers}/>
        <Route path="/following" component={Following}/>
        <Route path="/stars" component={Stars}/>
      </InformationContainer>
    </div>
  </ProfileContainer>
  );
};

const App = () => {

  return (
    <section> 
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" render={()=><Home />}/>
        <Route path="/pullrequests" component={PullRequests}/>
      </Switch>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch matches the first route and ignores all the later routes, so you need to change the order of your routes since `/pullRequests` will also match `/`

```
const App = () => {

  return (
    <section> 
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/pullrequests" component={PullRequests}/>
        <Route path="/" render={(props)=><Home {...props}/>}/>
      </Switch>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: this works. Will there be an issue if I add another route?

Comment: @peterflanagan, you need to make sure that the route paths that are prefixes to some other paths need to places at the end

Comment: The other option that you have is to make use of exact prop, but it might not be a great idea if the route has nested routes

Comment: just a bit confused tho `Switch matches the first route and ignores all the later routes` - in my original code it shouldn't have matched `/`, but should have kept going until it matched `/pullrequests`, correct?

Comment: In your code `/` was places before `/pullrequests` and hence `/` matched and pullRequest was never rendered. As I said, `/pullrequests` will match `/` as well as `/pullrequests`

Comment: You might wanna look at this https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/exact-bool